# angularjs ngRoute override

Tags: angularjs

I want to override some function inside `ngRoute` service of AngularJS. Such as function `updateRoute()`. I don't want to update `ngRoute` file. So I can update or downgrade version of AngularJS easily (without update core files). Here is a sample.

**Original function**

```
function updateRoute() {    
   template = $http.get(templateUrl, {cache: $templateCache}).then(function(response) { return response.data; });                                  
}
```

**Updated function**

```
function updateRoute() {

   var loadedTemplate = function(isReload){
     template = $http.get(templateUrl, {cache: $templateCache}).then(function(response) {
       if(isReload){ $route.reload();} return return response.data;
     },function(error){
       // call loadedTemplate with isReload = 1
     })

   }
   call loadedTemplate              
}
```

Comment: Dying to know the answer to this myself. Exploring hacking the core files at the moment. Not sure if due to scoping it's possible to override a function declared inside ngRoute.

In theory you should be able to create a service that inherits ngRoute, then create custom logic yourself and replace in the injector.